# Import file having different format in alternate rows

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to load 1 file using SSIS.
I am getting csv file of PIPE (|) delimited. but between every data row I am getting 1 row having only "-----------". If i try to load file as a PIPE delimited than i am not getting proper records.

I have 1 solution is I need to load entire row into single column, than i need to filter rows having "----", than i need to use transformation and split rows into columns. But it will be difficult to manage in case of changes.

Can anyone please give anyother Idea to load such files ?
[image]

Comment: I'd look into seeing if there was a way of deleting out alternate rows first before trying to read it in as a csv...

Comment: Why not use a conditional split and send the "----" lines to a multicast? You could (if you wanted!) then do a replace PIPE(|) on the remaining data with a comma and output this to a new .csv file. The next data flow would then read this .csv file. You would need to run this once before creating the second data flow as you would need an example .csv file to set up the new data source.

Comment: There could be many ways to handle this scenario but the better option is to ask client to send valid records only in the CSV,  If the file size of csv large for example 1GB it will be impact the performance because your package will look for bad records in the file it means you are checking each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this , i found solution is to read file in "ragged right" format.than filter out the records starting with "--".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a script task or transformation.  Look at every row in the script, and if it's all dashes then ignore it, otherwise parse it by the pipe character.